# Difference between static and dynamic linear regression

Tags: regression, time-series

A static linear regression has the form $y_t  = \mathbf{x}_t'\boldsymbol{\theta} + \epsilon_t$ while a dynamic linear regression has the form $y_t  = \mathbf{x}_t'\boldsymbol{\theta}_t + \epsilon_t$. Thus, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is allowed to vary over time in a dynamic regression while it is fixed for all time in static regression.

In terms of the generative process, for the static model, we would place a distribution on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ whose parameters are fixed for all time. We could then generate data by drawing $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ from this distribution and then generating $y_t$ given $\mathbf{x}_t$. For the dynamic model, we could place a distribution on $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}$ that depends only on data up through time $t-1$. We could then use this to generate a random $\boldsymbol{\theta}_t$ and then a random $y_t$. Thus, the key difference between the two models is that the parameters of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ in the static model are fixed for all time while they can change in the dynamic model.

I am confused when it comes to inference, however. If data were processed sequentially, what would be the difference between the sequence of parameter estimates that characterize the distribution of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ obtained by repeatedly refitting a static model and that obtained by forward filtering in the dynamic model? Don't both models depend on the same data, and hence, shouldn't they yield the same parameter estimates? If so, what advantage does the dynamic model actually provide?

Comment: The static model is expressed by the single equation, the only missing piece is the joint distribution of theta. The dynamic model needs further assumptions/expansions until you reach a time-invariant (in other words, static) representation that you can use for predictions.